# SQL Server : Breaking Comma Delimited String and matching values in a table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using SQL Server and have a "tags" column that has a string of of comma-separated tags. Is there a way to break the string up and place in another table and have them match to be able to easily see liked tags?

**Row 1:**

```
3years_andmore,access_ccc,access_sdl,associate_iii,ccc_tickets,desoto_counter,phone_call__property_tax,ticketing,trainer
```

**Row 2:**

```
3years_andmore,access_ccc,access_sdl,associate_iii,ccc_tickets,desoto_counter,phone_call__dmv,ticketing,trainer
```

**Row 3:**

```
5_minutes,access_ccc,access_sdl,associate_ii,ccc_tickets,desoto_counter,lessthan_3years,phone_call__operations___title_by_mail_inquiry,trainer
```

**Row4:**

```
access_ccc,access_sdl,associate_ii,ccc_customer_request_manager_other,ccc_tickets,desoto_counter,lessthan_3years,phone_call__associate_requesting_manager__customer_requesting_mr_brierton,trainer
```

There is no real order and not the same tags in field but is there a way to at least sort into a new table and break them up and match to see what tickets have the same tags?

```
SELECT 
    [id],
    [url],
    [external_id],
    [type],
    [subject],
    [description],
    [priority],
    [status],
    [recipient],
    [requester_id],
    [submitter_id],
    [assignee_id],
    [organization_id],
    [group_id],
    [collaborator_ids],
    [forum_topic_id],
    [problem_id],
    [has_incidents],
    [due_at],
    [tags],
    [via],
    [custom_fields],
    [satisfaction_rating],
    [sharing_agreement_ids],
    [followup_ids],
    [ticket_form_id],
    [created_at],
    [updated_at],
    [channel]
FROM 
    [Brierton].[dbo].[Tickets]
WHERE
    created_at BETWEEN '2017-11-01' AND '2018-08-23' 
    AND ',' + tags + ',' LIKE '%,' + 'ccc_tickets' + ',%'
```

Comment: Is there a finite number of possible tags? Ie do they come from some sort of existing list of possible tags, or are they some sort of input value and new tags are always possible?

Comment: The reason you are struggling here is because that design is really bad. It violates 1NF by shoving a bunch of values into a single tuple. You don't want a query to view this, you need to fix the design and then fix the data. There are tons of ways to split strings. Here is one. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/ Several other excellent choices can be found here. https://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings It looks like you have several of these in your table.

Comment: In all honesty, I'd probably consider a trigger and secondary table containing [ID], [TagID], and one tag as the data elements, indexed on ID, tag, TagID in order (TagID to ensure that no duplicate entries in the tag list cause an issue), Otherwise, the string splitting functions are your best bet. This assumes, of course, that you are allowed by your licensing to put a trigger on the underlying table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since version 2016 there's a built in `string_split()` function. To get the tags per ticket in a "more relational way" you could use:

```
SELECT t.id,
       x.value
       FROM tickets t
            CROSS APPLY (SELECT value
                                FROM string_split(t.tags, ',')) x;
```

From there you could aggregate to get the most used tags.

```
SELECT x.value,
       count(*)
       FROM tickets t
            CROSS APPLY (SELECT value
                                FROM string_split(t.tags, ',')) x
       GROUP BY x.value
       ORDER BY count(*) DESC;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=771cef7eb8ca88bcd324bde01cc57959)